# What should the return type for empty object?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
public Student process(Student st) { 
    return convert(st);
}

Private Student convert(Student st){  
  if(condition=true) {
    return Student.builder()
           .age(st.getAge())
           .marks(st.getMarks())
           .nationality(st.nationCode())
           .build();
   }
  return null;
}
```

In the above code i want return the Student object from convert method only if it satisfies a condition, then only i want to return Student object. Else i don't want to return the Student object. When i return null in else condition , I get null pointer exception. Is there any way to handle this without exception what all possibilities do i have to handle this ?

Comment: If you try to perform any operation with `NULL` you will get `NULL POINTER EXCEPTION'. Check the object is  `NULL` or not and perform an action

Comment: Use `Java 8` - `Optional<T>`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your obtained object is NULL after using `convert()` function and skip all operation's on such NULL value.

```
Student student = convert(studnetToConvert);
if (student != null) {
   // do some operation's with student
} // continue your code
```

Much more convenient way is to use `Optional` class to store Student object when returning it as value. `Optional` might be empty or filled. You can do operations like

```
Optional<Studnet> optionalWithStudent = Optional.of(convert(student))
Student s = optionalWithStudent.getOrDefault(new Student()) // get modified student or new student if condition inside convert() was not met
```

This way you are forced to add behavior for case's when Student is not present (Optional is empty) and forced to handle NullPointerException cases. I suggest you to look into some tutorial's with Java `Optional` class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning null or an empty object, instead opt to throw an exception that can be caught and handled in the case that the student cannot be converted.

```java
class StudentNotConvertedException extends Exception {
    // constructor(s)
}
```

```java
private Student convert(String input) throws StudentNotConvertedException {
    if (condition) {
        // return student from input
    }
    return new StudentNotConvertedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Optional`. Using it will ensure that instead of a null value, you will be sending the object of the Optional class, which can actually contain one value or can be empty.

```
private Optional<Student> convert(Student st){  
  if(condition=true) {
    Student studentOutput =  Student.builder()
           .age(st.getAge())
           .marks(st.getMarks())
           .nationality(st.nationCode())
           .build();
    return Optional.of(studentOutput);
   }
  return Optional.empty();
}
```

This is a good practice because the caller of your function will know the returned object can be empty. So the caller will write his code taking in care that what should he do when the returned object is empty.

```
Optinal<Student> studentOptinal = convert(st);
if(studentOptional.isPresent(){
  // Do the logic when the student follows the condition
}else{
  // I know that the student doesn't follow the condition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are going to process your `Student` object while you are not sure it is not `null`?

The best practice is check if your object is null or not.If it is `null`, depending on situation, you can throw an exception or just return an empty instance.